# Etymology of $PWD

Tags: shell, history, pwd

What is the etymology of `$PWD`? Is it an acronym?

I know there is a command `pwd` which prints working directory, but to my mind, it would have made more sense to name the variable `$CWD` for Current Working Directory, since shell variables contain data, rather than print them.

Comment: Present working directory...but you said it.  `print working directory`

Comment: @Jesse_b source?

Comment: "The PWD shell variable was introduced by ksh88, where it was described as the present working directory." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwd

Comment: @jasonwryan, that looks like an answer.

Comment: The [SunOS 5.5.1 ksh manpage dated 1995](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS+5.5.1&arch=default&format=html) uses "present working directory", but [the OpenBSD 2.0  ksh manpage (also dated 1995)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD+2.0&arch=default&format=html) uses "current working directory"... both were released in late 1996. Interesting.

Comment: @Wildcard I voted to close as opinion based.

Comment: @jasonwryan> The claim sounds dubious. The citation only links to the manpage of ksh88, which proves it did exist in ksh88, but absolutely doesn't prove it did not exist before.

Comment: @jasonwryan You could rewrite the question to make it one of history rather than opinion and then post your answer.

Comment: @spectras of course it is dubious, it is wikipedia...

Comment: @John1024 A rewrite won't save it; it is either "why is it called that", or "what does it stand for": in each case, it is subjective or unlikely to be authoratitively resolved by anyone here.

Comment: FWIW, the *command* `pwd` is described as *“print working directory pathname”* in Thompson&Ritchie's UNIX Programmer's manual 5th edition, dated June 1974. And it's not in the 3rd edition. Alas, I cannot find a copy of 4th.

Comment: @spectras 4h edition (and earlier) did not have `pwd` it seems.

Comment: `pwd` the utility and the `pwd` data structure field come from MULTICS.  I believe `PWD` the environment variable was added on UNIX.  It certainly predates `ksh88` though.

Comment: This is the kind of question that deals with angel's sex: "Why it's called PWD and not CWD?". Cause the creator of the command user print working dir as a verb(command), and makes sense to use a variable with the same name...

Comment: @jasonwryan If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

It Is an acronym. The acronym is:
Print Working Directory

*edit*
Historically, program output was printed on paper rather than on screens. So the **print** part is due to the output technology of the time that the command was developed.

Comment: And the etymology? What is the source for you assertion?

Comment: However @Sato has a good point, as a guide to multics written in 1980 shows the use of pwd as Print Working Directory http://multicians.org/multics-commands.html and this book agrees https://books.google.com/books?id=dFtY15Ng5xMC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=multics+pwd&source=bl&ots=5bX9-kO1-s&sig=KEg2ydVMIEr72YVxO5PgpkrkjXI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_-ng06LXAhUV5WMKHUMpCzUQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=multics%20pwd&f=false

Comment: And this may be the most telling yet: before Multics existed  there was CTSS (both from MIT) and its output was printed on paper cards instead of Cathode Ray Tubes. So *Print* was the appropriate term of the day. http://www.linfo.org/pwd.html